# How can i get the mvnw/mnvw.cmd without maven installed in advance(there doesn't exist any maven on computer at all)?

Tags: maven, maven-wrapper

I know that we can run the command `mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper` to generate the Maven Wrapper files, but what I'm wondering is that

1. what if there's no maven installed in advance, how should we generate the Maven Wrapper files for new or old projects?
2. Should we get the mvnw scripts first and where can we download it?
3. And I also want to know what is the source file in [Apache Maven Wrapper 3.2.0 (Source zip)](https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/download.cgi) used for?

I want to use the maven wrapper for my projects and I want to rearrange my projects as well as use the maven wrapper to replace all my installed maven.

Comment: If you use Maven wrapper you usually cal `./mvnw ..` this means the `mvnw` is a script which checks if Maven is there (more accurate particular location in your local `$HOME/.m2/repository`) and if not found it will download it...

Comment: @khmarbais, I know that the mvnw script is used for checking and downloading maven for user who uses it, but if i haven't installed maven and there doesn't exists mvnw script on my computer, how can I get the mvnw script for my new project?(I mean where can I get the mvnw script for my new projects?)

Comment: usually the mvnw script is checked in your project...

Comment: @ khmarbais , so if now i'm the project initializer and i want to use the maven wrapper, i should install maven in advance, right?

Comment: Technically you can but you don't need to..... the question is which project initializer you are using ... for example the https://start.spring.io/ will do that by default to create mvnw script etc.

Comment: I get it, much thanks.